# Running J scripts via command prompt on Win 10

Tags: scripting, command, prompt, j

How can I run J scripts from the console (cmd.exe or Powershell).I tried to set the path to jconsole.exe in Environment Variables but when I tried to launch it via cmd.exe, I get an error message that 'jconsole' is not recognized as an internal command or... I have done this successfully in the past for different command line tools.
Also, how do I set the default directory in J so that I don't have to type the full directory path every time I run a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jconsole.exe` works just like any other application in that regard. Once you've added the path to the file in your `PATH` variable, you can run it in a cmd session without specifying the whole path.

In my case, if I open `cmd.exe` and add the path to J binaries to my `PATH` (be sure not to add any quotes!):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\j901\bin;
```

Then check that it has been successfully added to the end by typing `PATH` and pressing Enter. Then I can successfully start J in that session by just typing `jconsole.exe`.

Note that this will only work for the current instance of `cmd.exe`. If I want it be available every time I open a new `cmd.exe` session, the I'd add it to the `Path` variable for my User using the Environment Variables Settings.

You mention that you've tried setting the path in Environment Variables, but it might be worth explicitly stating the directory where J is installed on your computer and what you've added to the `PATH`.

Have you confirmed in your `cmd.exe` session, that the path has been successfully amended?

Comment: Yes, I can now run jconsole from cmd.exe

Comment: In my original post I had also asked about how to set the default directory in J. In my case, suppose I want to run a  file from the addons directory. Is there a configuration file or autostart file that I can edit?

Comment: Probably best to ask a separate question for that. If the current question is answered to your satisfaction, you could tick it off.